# How to post my radio buttons fields in mail file in magento?

Tags: magento-1.8

I had a form and i can post other values like name,email but I could not post the radio buttons values in mail file.Please anyone can help me.

My form

```
  <form action="" id="bookingtest" method="post">
<div class="fieldset">
    <ul class="form-list">
        <li class="fields">
        <div class="field">
            <label for="testname" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Test Name') ?> </label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="text" id="testname" name="testname" value="<?php echo $_GET['name']?>" class="input-text required-entry" title="<?php echo $this->__('Test Name') ?>" />
                </div>
            </div>  

            <div class="field"> 

            <label for="city" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('City') ?> </label>
                <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" id="city" name="city" value="<?php echo $_GET['city']?>" class="input-text required-entry" title="<?php echo $this->__('City') ?>" />
                </div>
        </div>
        </li>
        <li>

            <label for="location" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Location') ?> </label>
                <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" id="location" name="location" value="<?php echo $_GET['location']?>" class="input-text required-entry" title="<?php echo $this->__('Location') ?>" />
                </div>

        </li>
        <li class="fields">
        <div class="field">
            <label for="cname" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Name') ?> </label>
                <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" id="cname" name="cname" value="" class="input-text required-entry" title="<?php echo $this->__('Name') ?>" />
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="field">
         <label for="email" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getUsername()) ?>" id="email" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" />
                </div>
        </div>
        </li>
        <li>

            <label for="mobile" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Mobile Number') ?> </label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" id="mobile" name="mobile" value="" class="input-text required-entry validate-mobileno" title="<?php echo $this->__('Mobile Number') ?>" />
                        </div>
         </li>
          <li>
          <label class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Sample Collection') ?> </label></li>
          <li>
                <div class="radio_button">
                <input type="radio" name="radio" class="input-text required-entry validate-select" value="I will visit Lab"> I will visit Lab
                </div>
                <div>
                <input type="radio" name="radio" class="input-text required-entry validate-select" value="Visit me at home/office +Rs50.00" > Visit me at home/office +Rs50.00
                </div>
         </li>
         <li>
                <label for="testschedule" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Test Schedule') ?> </label>
                    <div class="input-box">
           <div style="float:left">
                        <input type="text" id="testschedule" name="testschedule" value="" class="input-text required-entry validation-failed" title="Test Schedule" style="width: 150px;"><div style="" id="advice-required-entry-testschedule" class="validation-advice">This is a required field.</div></div><div style="float:left">
                        <img style="" title="Select Date" id="date_select_trig" alt="" src="http://www.labwise.in/devel/skin/frontend/ultimo/default/images/xcalendar.gif.pagespeed.ic.nkzRZoIMTp.png">
          </div><div style="float:left;widht:50px">
                        <select name="hour" id="hour" class="input-select required-entry validate-select validation-failed" style="width: 50px;">
                                    <option value="">--</option>
                                    <option value="1">1</option>
                                    <option value="2">2</option>
                                    <option value="3">3</option>
                                    <option value="4">4</option>
                                    <option value="5">5</option>
                                    <option value="6">6</option>
                                    <option value="7">7</option>
                                    <option value="8">8</option>
                                    <option value="9">9</option>
                                    <option value="10">10</option>
                                    <option value="11">11</option>
                                    <option value="12">12</option>
                                 </select><div style="" id="advice-required-entry-date_time" class="validation-advice">This is a required field.</div></div><div style="float:left">
                            <b>:</b>
              </div><div style="float:left">
                            <select name="minute" id="minute" class="input-select required-entry validate-select validation-failed" style="width: 50px;">
                                    <option value="">--</option>
                                    <option value="1">1</option>
                                    <option value="2">2</option>
                                    <option value="3">3</option>
                                    <option value="4">4</option>
                                    <option value="5">5</option>
                                    <option value="6">6</option>
                                    <option value="7">7</option>
                                    <option value="8">8</option>
                                    <option value="9">9</option>
                                    <option value="10">10</option>
                                    <option value="11">11</option>
                                    <option value="12">12</option>
                            </select>
                </div><div style="float:left">
                            <select name="ampm" id="ampm" class="input-select required-entry validate-select validation-failed" style="width: 50px;">
                                    <option value="">--</option>
                                    <option value="1">AM</option>
                                    <option value="2">PM</option>
                            </select>
         </div><div style="float:left">
                    </div></div>
        </li>

    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
<p class="required"><?php echo $this->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>
    <button id= "submit"  type="submit" class="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Book Test') ?>" name="send" id="send2"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Book Test') ?></span></span></button>
</div>


 </form>

  <script src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('js')."calendar/calendar.js" ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>

   <script src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('js')."calendar/calendar-setup.js" ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>

   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('js') ?>calendar/calendar-win2k-1.css"  />
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/html_calendar')->setTemplate('page/js/calendar.phtml')->toHtml();?>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    if(Validation) {
     Validation.addAllThese([
['validate-mobileno','Enter correct mobile number (Eg:9986858483)',
   function(v){
    //var timePat ="^((\+){0,1}91(\s){0,1}(\-){0,1}(\s){0,1}){0,1}9[0-9](\s){0,1}(\-){0,1}(\s){0,1}[1-9]{1}[0-9]{7}$";

var timePat ="^{0,1}9[0-9](\s){0,1}(\-){0,1}(\s){0,1}[1-9]{1}[0-9]{7}$";
// var matchArray = v.match(timePat);
if(v.length > 0){
if(v.length !=10){
    return false;
   }else if(v[0]!=9 && v[0]!=8 && v[0]!=7){

    return false;
   }


return true;

}else {
return false;
}

}
   ]])
  };
   var dataForm = new VarienForm('bookingtest', true); 
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
   // <![CDATA[
 Calendar.setup({
 inputField : 'testschedule',
   ifFormat : '%d-%b-%Y',
showsTime: false,
 button : 'date_select_trig',
 singleClick : true,
 });
   // ]]>
</script>
```

Mail.phtml

```
   function sendMailAction(){
   //Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(24999);
   $email=$_POST['email'];
    $name=$_POST['testname'];
    $city=$_POST['city'];
    $location=$_POST['location'];

    $cname=$_POST['cname'];
    $mobile=$_POST['mobile'];

    $html=
   '<p>TestName: '.$name.'</p>
    <p>City: '.$city.'</p>
    <p>Location: '.$location.'</p>
     <p>Name: '.$cname.'</p>
      <p>Email : '.$email.'</p>
       <p>Mobile Number: '.$mobile.'</p>
     '

     ;
     $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
     $mail->setToName('admin');
    $mail->setToEmail($email);
       $mail->setBody($html);
       $mail->setSubject('Booking');
        $mail->setFromEmail('admin@labwise.in');
         $mail->setFromName("Labwise");
      //$mail->addBcc("admin@labwise.in");
      $mail->setType('html');// YOu can use Html or text as Mail format

   try {
      $mail->send();
         //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Your Order is successfully Completed');
       //Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl());
       //return '<h2>Your Order has been submitted. Thank you for using labwise.   </h2>';
    //$this->_redirect('');
   }
    catch (Exception $e) {
   //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Unable to send.');
   //Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl());
  //return '</h2>Unable to submit.</h2>'; 
   //$this->_redirect('');
   }
 }  
  echo sendMailAction();
```

Comment: echo $option=$_POST['radio']; did you get any value?

Comment: No value.it has not worked i have worked by keeping that

Comment: And one more thing the selected radio button should be displayed in the mail.(EX:If user selects i will visit lab the mail body should be Sample Collection:I will visit lab")

Comment: @QaisarSatti please reply me.

Comment: try Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('radio'); and check you are getting the value or not

Comment: where I need to add this code in mail file

Comment: $option=Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('radio'); use there

Comment: 'option' is not used any where in the form please check my form and add according to that

Comment: $option is variable $option

Comment: @QaisarSatti Satti yes I am getting and how i have to do for test schedule field

Comment: @Mouni you are not getting value of radio every time or when radio is not selected by user?

Comment: @Mouni  you will get radio value only if radio is selected

Comment: I got for radio button I need for Test Schedule

Comment: Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('testschedule');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function sendMailAction(){
   //Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(24999);
   $email=$_POST['email'];
    $name=$_POST['testname'];
    $city=$_POST['city'];
    $testschedule=$_POST['testschedule'];

    $location=$_POST['location'];
    $option=Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('radio'); 
    $cname=$_POST['cname'];
    $mobile=$_POST['mobile'];
    $hour=$_POST['hour'];
    $minute=$_POST['minute'];
    $ampm=$_POST['ampm'];

    $html=
   '<p>TestName: '.$name.'</p>
    <p>City: '.$city.'</p>
    <p>Location: '.$location.'</p>

     <p>Name: '.$cname.'</p>
      <p>Email : '.$email.'</p>
       <p>Mobile Number: '.$mobile.'</p>
      <p>Test Schdule: '.$testschedule.'&nbsp; '.$hour.':'.$minute.' &nbsp;'.$ampm.'</p>
       <p>Visit: '.$option.'</p>
     '

     ;
     $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
     $mail->setToName('admin');
    $mail->setToEmail($email);
       $mail->setBody($html);
       $mail->setSubject('Booking');
        $mail->setFromEmail('admin@labwise.in');
         $mail->setFromName("Labwise");
      //$mail->addBcc("admin@labwise.in");
      $mail->setType('html');// YOu can use Html or text as Mail format

   try {
      $mail->send();
         //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Your Order is successfully Completed');
       //Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl());
       //return '<h2>Your Order has been submitted. Thank you for using labwise.   </h2>';
    //$this->_redirect('');
   }
    catch (Exception $e) {
   //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Unable to send.');
   //Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl());
  //return '</h2>Unable to submit.</h2>'; 
   //$this->_redirect('');
   }
 }  
  echo sendMailAction();
```

Comment: where is Test Schedule field??

Comment: add also want the dropdown value too?

Comment: update the answer kindly check and feedback

Comment: you missed another quotation before $ampm

Comment: no quotation before $ampm see ur comment

Comment: <p>Test Schedule: '.$testschedule.'  '.$hour.':'.$minute.' '.$ampm.'</p> it is working u added that is not working

Comment: check now added space @Mouni my mistake..

Answer (score 2):

you have to check your posted data using

```
 $this->getRequest()->getPost()
```

in your `sendMailAction` check what value are getting in those array.Based on that you can get value of radio.

Comment: Where I need to place this code

Comment: in sendMailAction  function, before $email=$_POST['email']. this is for debugging purpose.

Comment: it has to display the selected radio button by the user.

Comment: but you have to check which array value are printed using above method.